# Get information about a pub package in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get information about some pub package in a command line script.

For example, maybe I want to know what the last version of the angular 2 package is.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pub.dartlang.org provides a JSON API which is also used by the `pub` command line tool.  There are also https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_client and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_pub_client which provide a Dart API for pub.dartlang.org. For more details see the source of the packages linked above.